# httpd ProxyPass with sticky sessions and DNS RR

Tags: tomcat, java, httpd, proxypass

I'm using apache httpd with ProxyPass and DNS RR and sticky Java sessions for Tomcat.

It's not working.

My apache config is:

```
ProxyPass "/" "balancer://mycluster/" stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://stest:8080/
</Proxy>

<Location "/balancer-manager">
    SetHandler balancer-manager
    Require host localhost
</Location>
```

When I do an `nslookup stest` on the httpd host I have 5 hosts that come back:

```
root@sproxy:/app# nslookup stest
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stest
Address: 10.0.0.7
Name:   stest
Address: 10.0.0.6
Name:   stest
Address: 10.0.0.8
Name:   stest
Address: 10.0.0.2
Name:   stest
Address: 10.0.0.5
```

Thus, my httpd server should route to one of these IP addresses until a `JSESSIONID` cookie is set and then it should be sticky for that IP.

The problem is, this does not work.  When I do:

`while true; do curl -b /tmp/cj.txt -c /tmp/cj.txt -w '\n' localhost/test-session-servlet/json ; done`

I get my servlet output, which includes the Tomcat host that I hit and the session id.

I would expect this to only hit one server, since the cookie gets set in `/tmp/cj.txt` and is passed to every request.  I get the same output with the above command as I do with:

`while true; do curl -w '\n' localhost/test-session-servlet/json ; done`

(note the above command does not use cookies, so it should be load balanced even *with* sticky sessions because it does not pass the cookie)

In essence, both curl commands send to different servers as if the sticky sessions are not enabled properly, but the first should not do this.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat and httpd are working as designed. The problem is the architecture you have set up is never going to work. You need the `route` in `httpd.conf` and the `jvmRoute` in `server.xml` to be set and consistent.

One possible solution is to explicitly define each of the stest hosts in your httpd.conf file. Something like:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.2:8080/ route=tc01
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.5:8080/ route=tc02
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.6:8080/ route=tc03
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.7:8080/ route=tc04
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.8:8080/ route=tc05
</Proxy>
```

You'll also need to set the `jvmRoute` on the `<Engine>` element in the `server.xml` of each Tomcat instance and ensure that it is consistent with the route defined above.

Comment: So how do I use RR DNS with an httpd reverse proxy & sticky sessions?

Comment: You can't. Logically it can't work. If there is only a single host defined, httpd has no way to route the request to the correct host.

Comment: There's a single host *name* defined, it resolves to multiple IP addresses.

Comment: Think about it. If httpd routes by host name, how can it control which of the multiple IP addresses it routes a request to? It can't. It has to route by IP address which means the BalancerMembers need to be defined by IP address not host name.

Comment: I understand that, but when using RR DNS your hostname resolves to multiple IP addresses - so it would be possible to support it...